# Jquery cascading dropdowns with php and catalyst

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, catalyst

I am trying to implement cascading dropdown menus within a catalyst web app. The objective is to select a database table in the first menu and have the columns in that table appear in the second menu. My strategy is to use Jquery with a PHP helper script to run the query against the database.

Jquery code:

```
$("#db_table").change(function() {
    console.log("dbtable changed");
    $("#db_field").load("[% c.uri_for('/field_get.php')%]?choice=" + $("#db_table").val());
});
```

PHP:

```
<?php
    $username = "webuser";
    $password = "webuser";
    $hostname = "localhost";

    $dbhandle = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password) or die("Unable to connect to MySQL");
    $selected = mysql_select_db("mousesom", $dbhandle) or die("Could not load database");
    $choice = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['choice']);

    $query = "SELECT column_name FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_name = '$choice';";

    $result = mysql_query($query);

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo "<option>" . $row{'dd_val'} . "</option>";
    }
?>
```

HTML:

```
Table:<select id="db_table">
   <option selected value="base">Choose a Table</option>
   <option value="neurons">Neurons</option>
   <option value="peaks_factors">Transcription Factors</option>
   <option value="peaks">Peaks</option>
   <option value="peaks_selection">Selection</option>
   <option value="peaks_histmods">Histone Modification</option>
</select>
Field:<select id="db_field">
   <option value="Placeholder">Please Select a Table</option>
</select>
```

I have thus far verified that the javascript request is firing, but I am not getting the expected response. Based on the log output from the Catalyst test server, it seems most likely the needed arguments are not being passed to the PHP helper script, instead being split off into query params by Catalyst instead...

```
[info] *** Request 8 (0.013/s) [17122] [Fri Jun 26 19:22:50 2015] ***
[debug] Path is "/"
[debug] Arguments are "field_get.php"
[debug] "GET" request for "field_get.php" from "10.21.136.40"
[debug] Query Parameters are:
.-------------------------------------+--------------------------------------.
| Parameter                           | Value                                |
+-------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+
| choice                              | peaks_histmods                       |
'-------------------------------------+--------------------------------------'
```

Clearly this is not what I want to happen and am wondering if Catalyst has another way of passing these params to the helper script or some other workaround. I've been searching various documentations and have, thus far, come up empty-handed. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your request is being handled as if it's a Catalyst action because you're telling it to when you use the template code `[% c.uri_for() %]`. If you're going to call a PHP script, it needs to be outside the Catalyst URI namespace, perhaps by putting it amongst your `root/static` resources, or somewhere else your webserver expects to find PHP resources.

Having said that, I do not understand why you would introduce PHP into this mix. A Catalyst controller that returns the list of column names should be trivial to implement. The following untested code assumes you have a database handle available in your Catalyst app called `$dbh`. Whatever DB abstraction layer you're using (DBIC?), there's a straightforward way to get this. You might also choose to create proper model code for this.

```
sub get_fields :Args(1) {
    my ($self, $c, $table) = @_;
    my $qry = "SELECT column_name FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_name = ?";
              # we'll have none of that nasty SQL injection-vulnerable code here...
    my $result = "";
    my @res = $dbh->selectall_arrayref($qry, { Slice=>{} }, $table );
    map { $result .= sprintf("<option>%s</option>", $_->{column_name} } @res;
    $c->res->body($result);
}
```

I will be the first to point out that this approach is not best-practice, but it might give you some ideas about how this should be done. (Hint: a better practice would be to return the column names as JSON, and handle creating `<option>` tags in jQuery, rather than creating a HTML snippet in your Catalyst Action. Because you might find a method that accepts a table name and returns its columns might be generically useful.)

---

**Update**

You can use Catalyst::View::JSON, and by putting your list of columns into `$c->stash->{json}`, it will Do The Right Thing, even if it is overkill for the use-case. You can also just convert to JSON and return it in `$c->res->body()`: if that is not empty, all template processing is bypassed. So what you need might be as simple as:

```
use JSON;

sub get_fields :Args(1) {
    my ($self, $c, $table) = @_;
    my @rows = $c->model('InformationSchema')->result_set('Columns')->search({table_name => $table});
    my $columnlist = [ map { $_->column_name } @rows ];
    $c->res->body(to_json($columnlist));
}
```

... but a bit more error-checking would be no bad thing.

Accessing from jQuery boils down to something like (again, untested):

```
$("#db_table").change(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "[% c.uri_for('/__your_module__/get_fields/') %]" + $("#db_table").val(),
        success: function(json){
            $.each(json, function(i, val) {
                $('#db_field').append($('<option>').text(val).attr('value', val));
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: This makes sense. I was taking this approach, quite simply, because I'm new to this and it's the first way I came across in my searching for a way to implement it. The solution you propose seems to be much better and I will give it a try. Just to be sure I'm on the right path, to take the JSON approach, I would need to write model code to do the DB query, then return the result as a JSON and store it in the stash? Do I need Catalyst::View::JSON for this? How do I access the JSON in the stash from jquery? Sorry for the newbie questions -- again, I'm very new to this!

Comment: I thought I had posted a comment to alert you that I'd updated my answer, but obviously not. Anyway, see my updated answer...

Comment: Thanks for the update! I did see your reply but was away for most of last week and am just getting back to this project. So far I have gotten things working with the html snippets and I think it should be pretty straightforward to modify it to work with the JSON output, based on the information you gave above. Can't thank you enough for all your help!